# How to check a dictionary for a class object value?

Tags: python, class, object, dictionary, key

I have a dictionary, named

```
descendDict
```

And it contains 4 keys which are class objects, which have values that are both letters and other class objects.

Now what I'm trying to do is sort through the dictionary, and call out different actions if the value brought up in the dictionary is a class object, or if it is a letter:

```
for x in descendDict:
    print x, descendDict[x]
        for y in descendDict[x][0]:
            if y != (classObject?):
                #Action
            for x in descendDict:
                for z in descendDict[x][0]:
                    if z != (classObject?):
                        if y == z:
                            dist = 0
                        else:
                            dist = float(nodeDict[y]) + float(nodeDict[z])
```

In the if statements:

```
if... != (classObject?):
```

I am trying to determine whether the variable in the dictionary is, or is not a class object, but i just dont know how to do this.

Here is one the entries:

```
<__main__.Node instance at 0xb6738> ([<__main__.Node instance at 0xb6710>, 'A', <__main__.Node instance at 0xb6760>], '0.1')
```

I am sorting through it's first keys list, but i am trying to figure out if the values in the list are a class object, or a letter.

Comment: `if isinstance(d[x],MyClass):`

Comment: What do you mean by class objects ? class instance ? and what do you mean by letter ? strings ?

Comment: If you only have two types ("class object" or "letter") you can test if it's a "letter" instead IMHO i think it will be easier, assuming that a letter is a string, you can do: ``isinstance(d[x], basestring)`` .

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to create your own object dispatch system. Stop doing that, and refactor this to just use the python object system.

Comment: -1 for a misleading question. The answer you've picked does not deal with class objects, but class instances.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you mean by "class object" since everything in Python is a first-class object.  If you're trying to figure out if it's an instance of a specific class you can just use `isinstance`

```
if isinstance(y, someClass):
    # do stuff
```

Comment: ahh, thank you so much, my code works perfectly now, i was able to check for the class instance i created earlier.

Answer (score 1):

its better to define a method in your class then say

```
if hasattr(d[x],myClassMethodName):#then do this
else:#not a member
```

this method of checking allows much greater flexibility

for @RussellBorogove

```
 try:
    d[x].myMethod(*args,**kwargs)
 except:
    print "This is not an instance of my class and maybe a letter"
```

Comment: +1 because it is better, but this just demonstrates that this is a way for OP to create his own half-baked object system.

Answer (score -1):

You probably want `isinstance(x,type)`:

```
x = str
isinstance(x, type)
#=> True     

class x(object):pass    
isinstance(x, type)    
#=> True

class x:pass    
isinstance(x, type)
#=> False

x = "foo"
isinstance(x, type)
#=> False
```

Obviously, you'll have to stick to new-style classes, but you should be anyway.

However, it sounds like you're somehow trying to create your own object dispatch system. I strongly recommend that you move to some kind of common base class for all of your objects, and use method dispatch combined with higher-order methods to achieve whatever you're trying to do.

Comment: @RussellBorogove The accepted answer is to use `isinstance`, and in any case, the question is how to detect a "class object". Do you have a better method, or do you mindlessly downvote any answer with `isinstance` in it? Further, you clearly did not bother to read my final paragraph.

Comment: So are you going to downvote my other 200 answers now, or stop at 3?

Comment: I didn't find your final paragraph compelling, because it wasn't presented in a way that would be helpful to a novice Python programmer. There's no need to take it so personally.

Comment: @RussellBorogove I take unthinking, robotic reactions personally wherever I come across them.

Answer (score -1):

In Python it's common to use the "easier to ask forgiveness than permission" (EAFP) model, which looks like:

```
for y in collection:
    try:
        # treat it like it's a Node
        y.actionMethod()
    except AttributeError:
        # that method doesn't exist, so it's not a Node
        # do something else with it
        print y
```

This is preferred over using `isinstance()`, because it allows you to define several otherwise unrelated classes each with their own `actionMethod()` without having to change this dispatch code.

Comment: can someone concretely explain why EAFP is considered better than LBYL? as with LBYL its more clear to the reader what is happening and one of the core tenets of python is readibility and simplicity (I guess this is really a question in its own right)

Comment: -1 The question does not identify a single method which OP is looking for, and does specify that OP is looking to differentiate between types.